# Having callback within Node Promises

Tags: node.js, bluetooth-lowenergy, bleno

Using child process I execute a Python script does something a spits data back. I used a Node promise to wait until I get the Python data.

The problem I am facing is there is a callback for an anonymous function, the callback takes two parameters one of which is the python data. Code below explains. How do I call the promise, wait until it resolves then call the callback.

## Node Promise

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

function sensorData()
{
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
   {
      var pythonProcess = spawn ("python",[pythonV1.py"]);
      pythonProcess.stdout.on("data", function(data)
      {
         resolve(data);
      });
   });

 }
```

### Anonymous Function

```
...
onReadRequest : function(offest, callback)
{
   #============DOES NOT WORK=========================
   sensorData()
  .then(function(data) 
  {
     callback(this.RESULT_SUCCESS, data);
  })
  #===================================================

   #call promise, wait and then call callback passing the python data
   callback(this.RESULT_SUCCESS, new Buffer(#python data)
}
...
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know that your pythonProcess will only return one line of data, it's bad practice to call resolve() on every stdout data call.  It would be much better to collect data until the process closes, and return it all at once.

I'm also not used to dealing with buffers, so I'm casting stuff to strings here...

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

function sensorData()
{
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
   {
      var output = '';
      var pythonProcess = spawn ("python",[pythonV1.py"]);
      pythonProcess.stdout.on("data", function(data)
      {
         output += data.toString();
      });

// Not sure if all of these are necessary
      pythonProcess.on('disconnect', function() 
      {
         resolve(output);
      });

      pythonProcess.on('close', function(code, signal)
      {
         resolve(output);
      });

      pythonProcess.on('exit', function(code, signal)
      {
         resolve(output);
      });
   });

 }


...
onReadRequest : function(offest, callback)
{
   #call promise, wait and then call callback passing the python data
   sensorData()
      .then(function(data) 
      {
         callback(this.RESULT_SUCCESS, data);
      })
      .catch(function(err) 
      {
         // Do something, presumably like:
         callback(this.RESULT_FAILURE, err);
      });
}
...
```

Comment: FYI, it's not "unsafe" to call `resolve()` more than once, but it probably doesn't do what the OP wants.  After the first call, the subsequent calls are just safely ignored.  So "unsafe" is not really the right word.

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware that subsequent calls were dropped, I assumed it was like calling a callback multiple times.  Thanks for the correction!

Comment: Sorry I explained my self badly, placing the `callback` within  `sensorData().then function`, does not work. The `callback` is for the first anonymous `function(offset, callback)`, so placing it inside another anonymous function does not work. I can't think of a work-around.

Comment: My python code returns one line of data, so i didn't bother with the collecting the output then resolving.

Comment: It should work though, because the .then() anonymous function is within the onReadRequest one, so it should inherit its scope.  What if you forgot about promises for this use and just passed the callback function into SensorData, so SensorData could call it directly?